# Does the following set contain the Borel $\sigma$ algebra?

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose I have $X = \{(2^{-n-1},2^{-n}]:n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}\}$ and $ K = \sigma(X)$ where $\sigma(X)$ is a sigma algebra. My question is does $K$ contain the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: There is some bracket missing: $(2^{-n-1},2^{-n}$ ...

Comment: I suspect $\sigma(X)$ is meant to be the sigma algebra generated by $X$, i.e. the "smallest" sigma algebra that contains $X$.

Comment: In which space are you working? In $\mathbb R$ or perhaps in $(0,1]$? Give that information in your question (not in a comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Define $\mathcal{A}:=\left\{ A\mid A\cap\left(0,1\right]\text{ is a union of elements of }X\right\} $

In $X$ we recognize a countable partition of $(0,1]$ so $A\in\mathcal A\Rightarrow A^c\in\mathcal A$, and $A_1, A_2,\dots\in\mathcal A\Rightarrow\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathcal A$.

Then $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra with $X\subseteq\mathcal{A}$
so that $\sigma\left(X\right)\subseteq\mathcal{A}$.

However $\mathcal{A}$ does not contain the Borel $\sigma$-algebra.

Note for instance that singleton $\{0.5\}\notin\mathcal A$.

Comment: What and why are my immediate thoughts. What is $A$ and why does this example not contain the Borel $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: The elements of $\mathcal A$ are sets $A\subseteq\mathbb R$ (or $A\subseteq(0,1]$ if you prefer to work on space $(0,1]$) that have a certain property (their intersection with $(0,1]$ is a union of elements of $X$). Is e.g. singleton $\{\frac12\}$ such a set? No. So this singleton does not belong to $\mathcal A$. However every singleton belongs to the Borel-sigma algebra. This shows that $\mathcal A$ does not contain the Borel sigma algebra, as said.

Comment: Essential is here that $A\in\mathcal A\Rightarrow A^c\in\mathcal A$ which finds its cause in the fact that the sets belonging to $X$ form a countable partition of $(0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

Set $X_i := (2^{-i-1},2^i]$, $i \in \mathbb{N}_0$, and define

$$\mathcal{A} := \left\{ \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i; I \subseteq \mathbb{N}\right\},$$

i.e. each element of $\mathcal{A}$ can be written as a countable union of the sequence $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$. Claim: $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. Indeed:

- $X=(0,1] \in \mathcal{A}$: Obvious.
- Let $A \in \mathcal{A}$. By definition, we can find $I \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $$A = \bigcup_{i \in I} X_i.$$ Hence, $$A^c = \bigcap_{i \in I} X_i^c.$$ Since the sets $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ are a countable (disjoint) partition of $X$, we find $$X_i^c = (0,1] \backslash (2^{-i-1},2^{-i}] = \bigcup_{j \in I_i} X_j$$ for $I_i := \mathbb{N}_0 \backslash \{i\}$. Thus, $$A^c = \bigcap_{i \in I} \bigcup_{j \in I_i} X_j = \bigcup_{i \in J} X_i$$ for $J := \bigcap_{i \in I} I_i$. This shows $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$.
- Let $(A_j)_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. Then there exists $I_j \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that $$A_j = \bigcup_{i \in I_j} X_i.$$ Consequently, $$\bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} A_j = \bigcup_{j \in \mathbb{N}} \bigcup_{i \in I_j} X_i \in \mathcal{A}.$$

Since $X \subseteq \mathcal{A}$, we conclude $\sigma(X) = K \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. On the other hand, $\mathcal{A}$ does *not* contain the Borel $\sigma$-algebra (e.g. $A := \{1\} \notin \mathcal{A}$, this follows directly from the definition of $\mathcal{A}$).